# Failed loading gRPC binary module (gRPC php tutorial)

Tags: php, node.js, linux, grpc

I am working through [gRPC Basics - PHP Tutorial](https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/php.html).
I am having trouble on the following step:

```
$ cd ../../node
$ npm install
$ cd dynamic_codegen/route_guide
$ nodejs ./route_guide_server.js --db_path=route_guide_db.json
```

It causes the following error message:

```
throw error;
    ^

Error: Failed to load gRPC binary module because it was not installed for the current system
Expected directory: node-v57-linux-x64-glibc
Found: [node-v64-linux-x64-glibc]
This problem can often be fixed by running "npm rebuild" on the current system
Original error: Cannot find module '/home/vantage/grpc/examples/node/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vantage/grpc/examples/node/node_modules/grpc/src/grpc_extension.js:53:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vantage/grpc/examples/node/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:144:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
```

It seems that nodejs is looking for 'node-v57-linux-x64-glibc' but finding 
'node-v64-linux-x64-glibc'.  The file it's finding is the one that comes with the gRPC examples. `./examples/node/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-linux-x64-glibc`.  Therefore I think the problem is with my node installation.  I have seen many similar posts and tried many of the suggested answers with no good results.
For example:

`npm rebuild`

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

`npm install --target=10.0.0 --target_platform=linux --target_arch=x64`

My operating system is 'Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS'.
The node installation on my machine is from https://nodejs.org/en/download/ (Linux Binaries (x64)).  I installed it by following the instructions at https://github.com/nodejs/help/wiki/Installation.

My node version is: v10.15.1

npm version information:

```
{ 'grpc-examples': '0.1.0',
  npm: '6.4.1',
  ares: '1.15.0',
  cldr: '33.1',
  http_parser: '2.8.0',
  icu: '62.1',
  modules: '64',
  napi: '3',
  nghttp2: '1.34.0',
  node: '10.15.1',
  openssl: '1.1.0j',
  tz: '2018e',
  unicode: '11.0',
  uv: '1.23.2',
  v8: '6.8.275.32-node.12',
  zlib: '1.2.11' }
```

What is the solution?!

Answer (score 0):

The different version numbers in the error message correspond to the "module" version in the version information you provided. In this particular case, the package was installed for Node 10, but the error message indicates that you are loading it in Node 8. If you install with a target of `8.0.0` instead of `10.0.0`, it should work.

Comment: Tried `npm install --target=8.0.0 --target_platform=linux --target_arch=x64` but it did not fix the problem.

Comment: Sorry, you're saying that you installed the Node 8 version of the library and then when you try to load it it's still giving you the exact same error saying that only the Node 10 version is installed?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I don't know what version I installed.  I just tried running the `npm install --target=8.0.0 --target_platform=linux --target_arch=x64` command that I listed in my previous comment.  My install is was done from 'https://nodejs.org/en/download/ (Linux Binaries (x64)). ' as it says in my question.  Do I need to download and install a different version of Node?  From where?

Comment: I'm asking if you got the exact same error when you tried to run your program after running that command. In your original error there is a single item in the "Found" list. After you do that, are you getting exactly the same string as a single item in that list, or is it changing?

Comment: same:  `Error: Failed to load gRPC binary module because it was not installed for the current system
Expected directory: node-v57-linux-x64-glibc
Found: [node-v64-linux-x64-glibc]
`

Comment: OK, there is something very unusual going on here that I don't understand. I don't know why you seem to be running Node 8 when npm says you're running Node 10, and I don't know why that install command doesn't fix it. Can you edit the output of the `npm install` commands into your question?